# jQuery animation glitch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ctde5/8/) is a fiddle of the problem. I have a `span` with `display: inline-block` that contains another `span`, which I am slowly hiding. At the end, the container `span` momentarily "jumps back" to its initial position.

Is this a bug, or the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is when the animated (calculated) width becomes lower than 1px, the browser (at least my chrome) won't render that fraction, and the `#text` element snaps back to its original width.
You can view this behaviour if you increase the animation time to something very big (e.g. 25s) and watch the css-values in the console.

If you try this:

```
$('#text').delay(1000).animate({
    width: 1,
    height: 1,
    opacity: 0
}, 5000, function () {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

You'll get nearly the same animation without the snapping.

Comment: Aha. So it's a bug. The jQuery team should fix that.

Comment: I wouldn't say jquery is responsible for fixing this ;)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what your are trying to do exactly, but try this:

```
<div class='container'>
  <span>Text 1</span><br/>
  <span class='big'>Much more text</span>
</div>
```

and possibly add a width to the container

```
.container {
  border: solid 3px blue;
  width:200px;
}
```